# azure devop selfhosted agent, newman command not recognized

Tags: npm, postman, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, postman-newman

Trying to run my postman collection in azure devops inside a self-hosted agent.  When I try to run the command inside the agent "newman run postman_collection.json -e postman_environment.json -r cli,htmlextra" it's running fine.  But when I run the same through a a command line script task in release pipeline it's throwing the error "newman is not recognized..".  I also tried to have a npm task for newman installation i.e. "npm install -g newman" it's also throwing the erro "##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'newman'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a d...."

Answer (score 0):

> azure devop selfhosted agent, newman command not recognized

According to the error message "##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'newman" when you using the `npm install -g newman`, you could try to add `C:\Users\[BUILDSERVER-USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the PATH variable for the `[BUILDSERVER-USERNAME]` user.

You could refer to this document [How to fix the Newman task for Team Foundation Server silently failing](http://blog.vaneykelen.com/2019/01/09/How-to-fix-the-Newman-task-for-Team-Foundation-Server-silently-failing/) for some more details.

Besides, when we use command line to install the newman, it will take a few minutes to install it, so we need to wait for a few minutes before we using the command line:

```
"newman run postman_collection.json -e postman_environment.json -r cli,htmlextra"
```

You could add powershell task to sleep a few minutes：

```
echo "Sleeping for 10 mins..."
Start-Sleep -s 600
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I found the answer, the command prompt window that run the agent is not run as Administrator that's the reason it was not able to execute the newman command